# CRON Expression for All Mondays in a month except first one

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to come up with a CRON expression that will allow me to schedule a quartz trigger to run on every Monday in a month **except** the first one.

References:

- http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

CRON allows you to specify the nth occurrence of a day of the week easily. An expression for First Monday of the month would be:

```
0 5 0 ? * 2#1
```

Where the 2#1 represents the first Monday of the month (2 = day of the week, 1 being the nth occurrence)

However, if I try to do something like

```
0 5 0 ? * 2#2-2#5
```

OR

```
0 5 0 ? * 2#2,2#3,2#4,2#5
```

It complains with the message

```
 Support for specifying multiple "nth" days is not implemented.
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this in CRON?

Comment: This seems to be a common issue from what I have seen. The best answer seems to be use a [SimpleTrigger or CalendarIntervalTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/BiWeeklyTrigger.html).

Comment: @Jeremy, even then its difficult to achieve this use case. Only way i can think of is to have multiple triggers (one each for 2,3,4,5 monday's in a month)

Comment: Very good point. Personally I would create multiple triggers. The SimpleTrigger or CalendarIntervalTrigger was the only way I could think to (maybe) centralizing it into one Cron job.

Comment: @Srinivas: This was the approach I had to use. Having multiple copies of a single functional scheduler to cover all execution points look ugly but given the CRON expression limitation and my project's architecture I had no other option. It would be great if CRON can be enhanced to allow nth day ranges

Answer (score 0):

Where `cron` doesn't give you the expressiveness you desire<sup>(a)</sup>, it's a simple matter to change the command itself to only execute under certain conditions.

For your particular case, you know that the first Monday of a month is between the first and seventh inclusive and subsequent Mondays must be on the eighth or later.

So use `cron` to select all Mondays but slightly modify the command to exclude the first one in the month:

```
# mm hh dom mon dow command
   0  1   *   *   1 [[ $(date +%u) -gt 7 ]] && doSomething
```

That job will run at 1am every Monday but the actual payload `doSomething` will only be executed if the day of the month is greater than seven.

Some people often opt for putting the test into the script itself (assuming it even *is* a script) but I'm not a big fan of that, preferring to keep all scheduling information in the `crontab` file itself.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Don't be mistaken into thinking you can combine the day of week `1` and day of month `8-31` to do this. As per the man page, those conditions are OR'ed (meaning *either* will allow the job to run):

> Commands  are  executed  by `cron` when the minute, hour, and month of year fields match the current time, and when *at least one* of the two day fields (day of month, or day of week) match the current time

Combining those two will run the job on the first Monday and *every single day* from the eighth onwards.